# Is it possible to call a function when a variable changes in PHP?

Tags: php

```
function foo()
{ echo 'function called'; }
```

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
onchange($a, foo);
$a = "foo"; // echoes 'function called'
$a = "bar"; // echoes 'function called'
```

Instead of:

```
$a = "foo";
foo();      // echoes 'function called'
$a = "bar";
foo();      // echoes 'function called'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort of. You can use what's called a `setter`, a function designed to set a variable.

```
function setFoo ($value)
{
    echo 'in setFoo';
    return $value;
}

$a = setFoo('foo'); // echoes 'in setFoo'
echo $a; // echoes 'foo'
$a = setFoo('bar'); // echoes 'in setFoo'
echo $a; // echoes 'bar'
```

Comment: Ooh, so simple but I couldn't figure it out. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

In short: no. You shouldn't use global variables anyway, what means, that `foo()` should not know anything about `$a`, except you give it as a parameter